# How do i make an USB fingerprint scanner connected to a mobile phone/ tablet work successfully?

Tags: android, sdk, fingerprint

i am a final year student.. planning to do an android application for my final year project. I plan to do an attendance management system app for lecturers, where i plan to connect a usb fingerprint scanner to the (Lecturers) android phone/ tablet with android version 2.3 and above..using a mini USB OTG to USB 2.0 connector. The fingerprint scanner that i would be using are  most probably  either the Digital Persona U ARE U 4500 USB fingerprint reader or the Upek Eikon fingerprint scanner.

Im really lost and i dont know how to approach and where to start, beginning from choosing a suitable SDK and im in a doubt if the SDK might work/compatible with my android phone and also the android app which im going to create.

Please.. help me out sir,.... as the resources/info/ tips i received from lecturers and online sources were really not helpful.I really hope you will help this desperate soul out.Thank you

Tablet : Google Nexus 7
Mobile Phone:  http://instantcom.my/mobile-devices/m3-touch-n-type

Answer (score 5):

I think the best bet for you is neurotechnology embedded SDK for android. The SDK can actually achieve what you want to do. Goto [Their Site Here](http://www.neurotechnology.com)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to obtain a Motorola Atrix (the first version, which includes a fingerprint reader and an SDK to use it) or some other phone with the reader built-in (there may be some available now but I'm not certain).

If your only options are to use a USB-attached reader you will need to find hardware that has enough power to drive it as well as an SDK that can communicate with the sensor on Android via USB.

Comment: The Nexus 7 supports USB host with an adapter cable and has the USB host classes of recent Android versions.

Comment: You still have to write the USB driver using the Android USB API right?

Comment: If you're using the sensor-equipped Atrix (and you don't have a custom ROM that removes its support), the driver is built-in. If you're using a USB-attached sensor, then you need something to control it, of course.

Answer (score -3):

I would start here if you don't know much about making apps for android.

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

And the SDK is here, I use the plugins for eclipse which sets up everything into a nice android project for you.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html