# External biometric device connected to Android Device

Tags: java, android, fingerprint, usb-hostcontroller

I want to develop an android app in which user will be authenticated through bio-metric device.I stackoverflowed and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423875/how-do-i-make-an-usb-fingerprint-scanner-connected-to-a-mobile-phone-tablet-wor), but could not get any guidance to proceed.

I don't know which android devices support USB host. Again, I found [this](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/), but it does not give me any result.
Please tell me that

1. Is it possible to achieve this?
2. Biometric devices which support android
3. Android device requirement

I don't know how to proceed. Looking for prompt reply.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also struggling to find which of the devices support USB hosting. After trying various devices it is clear that just having **Android 3.1 or higher** does **NOT** guarantee that your phone support **USB Hosting**.

I came across this  [Google Spread Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gcfug6m-2tHfiJFExV3gShsO10PgbuYvF36Q31-dOcY/edit#gid=1918400659) which lists various devices with USB Hosting.

You can also contribute to this list by submitting your responses through this [Google Form](http://goo.gl/Zp2svF).

Hope this helps !